# vsftpd permissions for virtual users with Apache SUexec compatibility

Tags: apache-2.2, suexec, vsftpd

I run a linux server with Apache + SUexec where all virtualhosts htdocs folder are owed by specific users :

```
# ls /www/sites
drwxr-xr-x  4 vhost-sitea.com   vhost-sitea.com   4096 Oct 13 16:45 www.sitea.com/
drwxr-xr-x  3 vhost-siteb.com   vhost-siteb.com   4096 May 14 20:09 www.siteb.com/
drwxr-xr-x  5 vhost-sitec.com   vhost-citec.com   4096 Nov 22  2013 www.sitec.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 vhost-sited.com   vhost-sited.com   4096 Oct 25  2014 www.sited.com/
```

I want the owners of these websites to be able to connect through VSFTPD and manage their own folders. For that, each virtual user is named "user_a", "user_b"( ... ) based on its website.

My VSFTPD configuration, based on Chroot and Virtual users, is the following:

```
# cat /etc/vsftpd.conf
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/vsftpd/users/$USER  # Overridden by user_config_dir below
chroot_local_user=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_user_conf
```

and the user configuration file is (example with "user_a" for website "www.sitea.com") :

```
# cat /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_user_conf/user_a
local_root=/www/sites/www.sitea.com
write_enable=YES
```

Now my issue is, when this user tries to upload a file, VSFTPD uses the "vsftpd" unix user, which fails because the www.sitea.com folder and subfolders are owned by specific "vhost-sitea.com" user (as per SUexec configuration).

You have to understand that under SUexec, Apache "www-data" user is not used at all regarding www virtual folder rights so I cannot simply use it in "guest_username" directive.

Is there a way to specify a VSFTP daemon user for each virtual user that logs in, so that the VSFTPd daemon will write files under "vhost-sitea.com" user, when the virtual "user_a" user is connected with VSftp ?

Thank you for your help,
Ken.

Answer (score 0):

For the records, answering to myself : using bindfs and forcing file owner seems to be an interesting workaround, as I got the following :

```
# bindfs -u vsftpd /www/sites/www.sitea.com/ /home/vsftpd/users/user_a/mnt-www.sitea.com/
```

Here are the perms on the directory to mount :

```
# ll /www/sites/www.sitea.com/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 vhost-sitea.com   vhost-sitea.com 4096 Nov 10 20:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root              root        4096 Nov  8 20:37 ../
drwx------  2 vhost-sitea.com   vhost-sitea.com 4096 Nov  8 20:43 .cache/
drwxr-xr-x  5 vhost-sitea.com   vhost-sitea.com 4096 Nov 10 20:52 html/
drwxr-xr-x  2 vhost-sitea.com   vhost-sitea.com 4096 Nov 10 20:42 packages/
```

Now let's see the perms on the mounted point :

```
# ll /home/vsftpd/users/user_a/mnt-www.sitea.com/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 vsftpd vhost-sitea.com 4096 Nov 10 20:42 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root   root        4096 Nov 10 22:12 ../
drwx------ 2 vsftpd vhost-sitea.com 4096 Nov  8 20:43 .cache/
drwxr-xr-x 5 vsftpd vhost-sitea.com 4096 Nov 10 20:52 html/
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsftpd vhost-sitea.com 4096 Nov 10 20:42 packages/
```

However it could be interesting if anyone of you has a much better solution - let's say a less "Quick and Dirty" one :)

++

Comment: I've tried that approach with no success, but using local users. What distro do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the vsftpd virtual user system connecting each virtual user to a different system user, so **`guest_username` have to be different for each virtual user**, instead of unique.

**You have to define `guest_username` in each virtual user's configuration file**, not in the main config file. Besides **its value has to be the system user that you use in your suEXEC configuration**, for that particular virtual host.

In example, for the virtual user virtual_user connected with the system user local_user, that has an Apache virtual host in /www/sites/local_user, `/etc/vsftpd.conf` will be:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/www/sites/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_user_conf
```

`/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_user_conf/virtual_user` will contain just one line:

```
guest_username=local_user
```

To simplify the configuration I have named the folder that contain the Apache virtual host with the local_user. This way you can set up local_root just once in /etc/vsftpd.conf and remove it from each virtual user configuration file.